# Sending Query Results from MySQL to .ejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express

I've just begun learning node.js and was trying to fetch query results from MySQL and send them to an ejs file. My original app.js looked like this.

Here's my original app.js:

```
var app = express();
var client = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'user',
    password: '',
    database: 'DB_practice'
});
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    var result;
    fs.readFile('list.ejs', 'utf8', function(error, data){

        client.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(error, results){
            result = results;
            console.log("Query results(inside): " + JSON.stringify(results));             
        });
        console.log("Query results(outside): " + JSON.stringify(results));
        response.render(__dirname + '/list', {data: result} );

    });
});
```

But I noticed that having the render() method outside the client.query() block didn't execute the code in order. console.log("Query results(inside): " + JSON.stringify(results)); line prints the results out fine, in an array form. But when I print it outside(console.log("Query results(outside): " + JSON.stringify(results));), it returns undefined, which would mean that the "inside" print function is executed after "outside" print function. So I tried placing the render() inside the query block as such:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    var result;
    fs.readFile('list.ejs', 'utf8', function(error, data){

        client.query('SELECT * FROM test', function(error, results){
            result = results;
            response.render(__dirname + '/list', {data: results} );
            console.log("Query results(inside): " + JSON.stringify(results));             
        });
        console.log("Query results(outside): " + JSON.stringify(results));


    });
});
```

which complains the variable to which I pass the query results in list.ejs is undefined. Here's the portion from list.ejs:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var row =<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>
    </script>
    <% row.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/delete/<%= item.id %>">DELETE</a></td>
        <td><a href="/edit/<%= item.id %>">EDIT</a></td>
        <td><%= item.id %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
        <td><%= item.phone_no %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
```

It says that row is undefined.

I've been struggling with this for a couple days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `list.ejs` with given below code -

**list.ejs**

```
<% data.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/delete/<%= item.id %>">DELETE</a></td>
    <td><a href="/edit/<%= item.id %>">EDIT</a></td>
    <td><%= item.id %></td>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.phone_no %></td>
</tr>
<% }); %>
```

Anything within tags <%- %> will print to output with unescaped HTML data.

Comment: @user3369873, Hope this will help to resolve your issue.